# Generar un código que no se repita

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario para crear empresas en mi proyecto.

Para que un usuario se pueda asociar con su empresa él debe de ingresar un código de la empresa, pero no sé cómo generar un código que no se repita con otro en la base de datos.

En este caso tengo una tabla de empresas, con id, Empresa, Nit y el código y la tabla de usuarios donde verifico si el código que él ingresó está en una empresa y después hacosio el id con la llave foránea.

La pregunta concreta es:

> ¿Cómo genero un código que no se repita con otros?

NOTA: El código sea de 5 dígitos para que no sea tan largo.

Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: Hola, puedes añadir lo que has intentado?

Comment: ¿El campo del código es una clave única en la tabla? ¿Quieres que los códigos sean generados aleatoriamente entre 10000 y 99999 para que siempre tengan 5 cifras (sin 0 a la izquierda)? ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Una posibilidad es generarlos antemano.  Crear una tabla que no permita numeros duplicados.  Generar un numero al azar, y insertarlo en la tabla.  Si ya existe, va a echar un error que puede ignorar.  Cuando tiene 100,000 filas, la table está llena.  Entonces cuando crea un empresa, SELECT numero FROM tabla LIMIT 1;

Comment: La forma más fácil sería, si no quieres hacer que el código sea el ID de la tabla, es primero hacer un `SELECT codigo FROM tabla ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1` y cuando se inserta la nueva empresa su código será el resultado de la consulta + 1.

Comment: Lo que tenia en mente es generar una codigo con `$codigo_generado =  rand(10000,99999)` y que se verificara por medio de una cosulta `SELECT codigo FROM usuarios WHERE codigo = $codigo_generado` y verificar que no tubiera ningun resultado

Comment: @aeportugal Entiendo pero si por casualidad cuando le sumes 1 tambien exista como se verificaria.

Comment: No va a existir porque `ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1` te va a traer si o si el mayor número que existe en ese campo codigo de la tabla. Obviamente esa consulta se hace a la hora de hacer el INSERT. PHP traerá de la BD el mayor código, le sumará 1 y lo insertará en la tabla junto con los otros datos de la nueva empresa.

Comment: La columna código la pondría como ```unique```, y así es imposible que se repita en la BD, ya que no te va dejar INSERTAR si este ya existe. Podrías generar un código aleatorio con ```$codigo = random_bytes(3);``` y antes de guardarla, verificas que no exista en la BD.

Comment: @aeportugal una pregunta la suma de 1 se hace con el query o toca hacerlo con php?

Comment: Se puede desde PHP o desde la BD, sin embargo yo sugeriría que lo maneje PHP. Que la tabla tenga su propio id autoincremental, pero que el numero del campo **codigo** sea asignado desde PHP, esto porque a veces los campos auto_increment se saltan números [dejando huecos](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+mysql+auto_increment+holes).

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono @aeportugal